# Mistaken duplicate JSON nested object - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I have a Rails API that returns JSON using the rabl gem. Here's the `/show` template which is extended to the `/index` template as well.

```
object @deal
attributes :headline, :text, :image, :id, :created_at

child :vendor do
    attributes :image_url, :id
end
```

Both `Deal` and `Vendor` have images, uploaded through CarrierWave/Fog to S3. The problem I'm seeing here is that my returned JSON includes and extra `image` object for `deal`. Like so:

`"deal":{"image":{"image":{"url":"httpxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}}`

In contrast, the JSON for vendor returns appropriately:

`"vendor":{"image_url":"httpxxxxxxxxxxx"}`

My uploaders are like below:

```
class DealUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   def store_dir
     "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end
end

# vendor image uploader
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Why am I getting this redundant `image` object?

Comment: What happens when you comment out the three child :vendor lines? What is the content of Vendor rabl template?

Comment: Same issue with `deal` unfortunately.

Comment: What is the content of Vendor rabl template?

Comment: I don't have one, `vendor` is being displayed as a child of `deal`.

Comment: Then shouldn't the deal attributes be: attributes :headline, :text, :image_url, :id, :created_at. That is, using :image_url instead of :image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
object @deal
attributes :headline, :text, :image_url, :id, :created_at

child :vendor do
    attributes :image_url, :id
end
```

Comment: Well that worked, thank you. Why does `image` return the extra object? Something to do with CarrierWave's uploader?

Comment: I expect because deal.image returns an image uploader object, and rabl is doing its best to represent the object in JSON. deal.image_url is a method that returns a string (the url to the uploaded file), so that's represented in JSON as just image_url: url_string.